# refine popup in search panel

Tags: usability, website-design, popup, search-results, requirements

Have 2 questions related to refine panel in search results.

1. How should we showcase more options in 1 category – should I add individual popup for each category or all options in 1 popup.  Have added 2 examples here, 1 is with only options related to one particular category [image]and 2nd is ebay example where we have all options, all category in one popup.[image] You can open this popup from any category see all link. Is this the better way to do it?
2. If I add auto triggered refine (as soon user select option , result get updated) than should I have back to original search link? Or should I add selected options with cross button. [image]

Answer (score 3):

Whether to split the menu up into categories depends on how many options you have available. What you should be thinking about is how quickly can a user scan the menu and find what they are looking for. In western cultures a user will read from left to right, top to bottom. The first example you give is a little cluttered looking and makes me do too much reading to find the options that I want to include in my search. It could be improved by subdividing the options into 3 distinct and clearly labeled columns, with column 1 being the cheaper ranges and column 3 the most expensive. Each column should then be ordered in a similar way (cheapest to most expensive) Then a user will look along the top from left to right, decide they want the cheaper options, then only have to scan down the column to find the one they want.

[image]

The ebay example works well for the vast amount of options they have available, but if you don't have this many in your use case it may be overkill.

In this case there may be a third way to do it. In the first example you provide the options all seem to be ranges of values. For this kind of use case I would consider providing the user with a slider bar to set their own value ranges.